# Как объединить два массива из хешей в один, не дублируя одинаковые значения?

Tags: ruby

У меня есть товар, распарсенный из .csv файла, хранится он в массиве из хешей. По факту это артикульный номер `article`.

```
data = [{:article=>"MGXG-15"}]
```

У меня есть описание товара, распарсенное из xml странички, которое тоже хранится в массиве хешей. Там есть тот же артикульный номер.

```
products = [{:article=>"MGXG-15", :title=>"Консоль Kilan", :price=>"38290.0"},
            {:article=>"eh_06", :title=>"Диван Juco", :price=>"145000.0"},
            {:article=>"LSP-9197", :title=>"Светильник настенный", :price=>"44800.0"}]
```

Подскажите, как по артикульному номеру `article` из `data` найти такой же артикульный номер в `products` и соотвественно подгрузить недостающие данные (в третью переменную к примеру).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стоит по возможности избавиться от лишнего копирования объектов. Компьютеру быстрее не "дополнить", а "заменить более полным".

Если во всех хэшмапах `data` есть ключ `:article`, то можно наивно выбрать соответствующие следующим образом:

```
data.map do |data_element| # O(data.length)
  article = data_element[:article]
  products.find { |product| product[:article] == article } # O(products.length)
end
```

Если `products` длинный, есть смысл его предварительно проиндексировать по `:article`:

```
products_index = products.each_with_object({}) do |product, index|
  index[product[:article]] = product
end
```

...и вместо `products_find { ... }` использовать `products_index[article]` (`O(1)`).

Если вам надо всё-таки *дополнить*, вместо `map` делайте `each`, а внутри дописывайте атрибуты прямо в `data_element` с помощью `merge!`.

Comment: У меня в .csv файле есть три артикула. И действительно, когда я перебираю `data.map` у меня получается три хэша. Но не те! А три одинаковых - первый хэш, который находится в переменной `products` повторяется три раза. Но при этом в переменной `article` находятся нужные артикулы.

Comment: `[{:article=>"MGXG-15", :title=>"Консоль Kilan", :price=>"38290.0"}, {:article=>"MGXG-15", :title=>"Консоль Kilan", :price=>"38290.0"}, {:article=>"MGXG-15", :title=>"Консоль Kilan", :price=>"38290.0"}]` Это получается когда перебираю `data.map`

Comment: А нужно искать по тем артикулам, которые находятся в переменной `article`. Я так понимаю дело в строчке `@products.find { |product| product[:item] }`

Comment: @Chumak там действительно был косяк :) Сейчас я его поправил, но попробуйте интереса ради это отладить самостоятельно, не смотря в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает) Но не совсем понял как работает индексация в данном случае.

Comment: @Chumak поиск по массиву перебором заменяется на один поиск в хэшмапе. Вот этот хэшмап и есть индекс. Но предварительно его надо построить.

Comment: Буду разбираться) А не подскажите еще, мне нужно эту сохраненную обновленную таблицу каким-то образом скачать(в формате .csv для дальнейшей загрузки в 1С). Может есть гем какой для этого?

Comment: @Chumak а вам бы всё готовый гем! :D Тут нет необходимости в геме, берите [`CSV`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Writing) и напишите несколько строчек кода сами.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо :D